# Scalar product in L2(0,1)?

Tags: calculus, hilbert-spaces

Is $s(f,g) = \int_0^1 f(x)g(1-x)dx$ a valid scalar product in $L^2(0,1)$?

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Real scalars, I presume?

Comment: Take $f(x)=1$ for $x\in[0,1/2]$ and $0$ otherwise. Compute $s(f,f)$.

Comment: Or $f(x) = 1-2x$. The positive definiteness isn't given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not: The condition

$$s(f, f) = 0 \implies f = 0$$

does not hold. Try coming up with a specific example to show this; a piecewise defined function could work well here.

---

In fact, choosing any function $f$ which is negative on $[0, 1/2]$ and positive on $[1/2, 1]$ will give an example of

$$s(f, f) < 0$$

for the integrand will always be negative.